# How can I post Facebook fan page status updates to my WordPress blog?

Tags: rss, facebook

Is it possible to get an RSS feed of Facebook status updates from a Page rather than a Profile? I want to use the feed in WP's RSS feed widget.

[It's easy to pull statuses from a profile page](http://isaacadams.com/2011/10/27/how-to-add-your-facebook-status-to-wordpress/#comment-150). I did this using an RSS feed widget. I tried doing the same thing for a fan page, but Facebook forces me to switch contexts (from viewing as the a page to viewing as myself), after which I'm redirected to my own status feed.

There is an RSS for notifications, but I want it for statuses, not notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure the Facebook fan page RSS feed URL is like this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=atom10&id=YOURFBFANPAGEID
```

The fan page ID is the string of numbers at the end of the URL when viewing the page, for example, Jon Stewart's fan page id is 193859733506:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Jon-Stewart-for-President/193859733506
```

So you can do your normal RSS feed solution which takes entries and uses them in your Wordpress site, and use that URL format above for the fan page you are after.

Comment: do you know if the same thing is possible with Facebook Groups?